# How to read a sheet in CSV using groovy

Tags: csv, groovy

My CSV file has 3 sheets (Sheet1,Sheet2 and Sheet3) created.

How would I read an element from Sheet2.

Any suggestions would be of great help.

Comment: Could you please provide more information (read [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) page for hints how to do it)?

Comment: Irrespective of element, basically I'm trying to access a specific sheet in csv.

Comment: What do you mean "sheet in CSV" file? Can you paste exemplary CSV file, provide information what you have already tried to do and what is the expected result? Otherwise your question is very unclear and it can be closed due to lack of MCV example.

Comment: I do not think there is sheet in csv, but a spread sheet has.

Comment: Sounds like you want something like Poi (https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html)

Comment: @Rao I guess you're right.. Looks like there's no SHEET concept in CSV file..

Comment: Hey @SzymonStepniak thanks for responding quickly and trying to understand my question.. As Rao said, there's no concept of SHEET in CSV file.. Hence I'm updating to the same CSV file.